# APEX: Making an update following a callout - DML error

Tags: salesforce, apex, dml

When I make a callout I would like to store the result in an object. But I get the following error message:

> DML currently not allowed An unexpected error has occurred. Your
>   development organization has been notified.

Can anyone help, please?

this is the code:

```
public with sharing class Tower_clientID
    {
        public String city{get;set;}
        public String temp{get;set;}
        public String Surname1{get;set;}


        public Tower_clientID(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)  
        {
            Account account=(Account)stdController.getRecord();
            account=[select Id,ShippingCity from Account where Id=:account.id];

            String AccountCity=account.ShippingCity;
            String reqBody='{"DocumentType":"ID","DocumentId":"'+AccountCity+'"}';
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

  request.setEndpoint('https://tow.turnkey.com/TOW30API/api/onboarding/get_clientByDocumentId');
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.setHeader('tow-domain', 'TR');
    request.setHeader('tow-language','en-GB');
    request.setHeader('tow-usercode', 'C32B3C53D238F6DCE44E34B');
    request.setHeader('tow-apikey', '1122334477889900');    

    request.setBody(ReqBody);

            if(response.getStatusCode()==200)
            {
            Map<String,Object> results=(Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
            city=String.valueOf(results.get('Id'));
            temp=String.valueOf(results.get('Name'));
            Surname1=String.valueOf(results.get('Surname'));

                account =[select Id,ShippingCity from Account where Id=:account.id];
            account.ShippingCity = 'New York';
            update account;
            } } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DML is not allowed in constructors, in your case it's the `Tower_clientID` method that's the problem.

Shameless plug, I'll cross-link my 6-years-old answer for more info: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28833/why-is-dml-not-allowed-in-constructor

Move the code (callout and update) into another method. Or keep the callout in constructor , you could display the results? But update would be explicit action, human clicking a button, understanding what he/she is doing, accepting the "side effects".

- If you're calling it from another apex class - call the constructor first, then the method.
- If you're calling from Visualforce (I mean you have `StandardController` in there) - you could make a button or use `<apex:page action="{!calloutHere}">` (it's not great though but if you really want it to happen as soon as page loads and you understand the risks...
- Similar for aura (use `init` handler) and lightning web components (use `@wire`? `connectedCallback`?)